# If product category is empty display text (php shortcode) Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show display a message when a product category has zero products.  I want to do this via shortcode please.

I've tried searching StackOverflow and search engines for some codes to work off of but have been unsuccessful.

```
$category = get_queried_object();
$theCount = $category->count;

function farmdish_no_prod_msg_shortcode( $atts ) {

    $a = shortcode_atts(array('slug' => ''), $atts );

    if( ( is_product_category( '' . $a['slug'] . '' ) ) && ( $theCount > 0 ) ){


    }else {
        return '<span>No Products!</span>';
    }

}

add_shortcode( 'no-prod-msg', 'farmdish_no_prod_msg_shortcode' );
```

I need to show a simple text message when there are zero products in a WooCommerce product category.  Thank your for any help!

Comment: move this code to inside the function `$category = get_queried_object();
 $theCount = $category->count;`

Comment: @Vel I tried this:   

function farmdish_no_prod_msg_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $category = get_queried_object();
    $theCount = $category->count;
   $a = shortcode_atts( array(

but it's showing no products when there are indeed products in the category.  I think something else is wrong with the code.

Comment: `get_queried_object` will work only on category page

Comment: what is the value of `$a['slug']`?

Comment: Oh okay, so thats why I'm having trouble.  I'm not putting this on a category page.  I need it to work on any page.  This is the shortcode I'm using:  [no-prod-msg slug="gluten-free"]  gluten-free is the slug of the category for this example but I want to use different category in the slug for different pages which is why im using an attribute for the shortcode.

Comment: `gluten-free` is category slug?

Comment: Yes it is the category slug

Comment: added as answer

Answer (score 0):

Shortcode is a wrong way of doing it.
You can do it by adding a woocommerce template file:

1. Create a folder named "woocommerce" in your theme directory (if not
   exists)
2. Create another folder inside it called "loop"
3. Create a file called "result-count.php" Add the following code to this file

   $total = wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' );
       if ($total === 0){
           echo 'NO PRODUCTS HERE BUDDY...';
       }

Comment: Thank you for the response.  However, I need a shortcode I can put anywhere on the site.  I don't think this solution works with a shortcode?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function farmdish_no_prod_msg_shortcode( $atts ) {

    $a = shortcode_atts(array('slug' => ''), $atts );


    $catObj = get_category_by_slug($a['slug']); 

    $theCount = $catObj->count;

    if( $theCount > 0  ){


    }else {
        return '<span>No Products!</span>';
    }

}

add_shortcode( 'no-prod-msg', 'farmdish_no_prod_msg_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  It's showing "No Products!" but I do have a 1 product in that category.  I removed the product from the category and it still says the same thing.

Comment: remove this `is_product_category( '' . $a['slug'] . '' ) )`

Comment: I changed that line to:

if( ( $theCount > 0 ) ){

but it still says no products when I do have a product in the category.

Comment: check the value of `$theCount `

Comment: I've copied the updated code into my functions.php file and used the shortcode on new page but it still shows no products when I do have products in that category. I'm not sure why its not working.

Comment: what do you mean by this?  check the value of $theCount

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198673/discussion-between-chad-fonger-and-vel).

Comment: Please share me category page screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
function farmdish_no_prod_msg_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts(array('slug' => ''), $atts );

    $catObj = get_category_by_slug($a['slug']); 

    $theCount = $catObj->count;

    if( $theCount == 0  ){
        return '<span>No Products!</span>';}
    }

add_shortcode( 'no-prod-msg', 'farmdish_no_prod_msg_shortcode' );`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).